# Python OSError not reporting errors

Tags: python, imagemagick

Ive got this snippet that Im using to convert image files to tiff.  I want to be informed when a file fails to convert.   Imagemagick exits 0 when successfully run, so I figured the following snippet would report the issue.   However no errors are being reported at all.

```
def image(filePath,dirPath,fileUUID,shortFile):
  try:
    os.system("convert " + filePath + " +compress " + dirPath + "/" + shortFile + ".tif")
  except OSError, e:
    print >>sys.stderr, "image conversion failed: %s" % (e.errno, e.strerror)
    sys.exit(-1)
```

Answer (score 5):

`os.system()` does not throw an exception if the return value is non-zero. What you should do is capture the return value and check that:

```
ret = os.system(...)
if ret == ...:
```

Of course, what you should *also* do is replace `os.system()` with [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system).

Answer (score 3):

A better think will be to use [check_call](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call) from the subprocess module, it raises CalledProcessError when the subprocess returned a non zero value.

Comment: This will have several advantages over using `os.system`—The Pythonic API the caller wanted, avoiding using the shell, and handling signals in a more normal way.

Answer (score 1):

You can access [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) directly through Python using PythonMagick ([download here](http://www.imagemagick.org/download/python/)). A more popular tool for image manipulation is [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/).

Answer (score 0):

`+` is generally a bad way to build strings in Python.

I would tend to replace `"convert " + filePath + " +compress " + dirPath + "/" + shortFile + ".tif"` with

```
import os.path
"convert %s +compress %s.tif" % (filePath, os.path.join(dirPath, shortFile))
```

That being said, you'd replace the whole `os.system` call using

```
from subprocess import check_call, CalledProcessError

newFile = "%s.tif" % (filePath, os.path.join(dirPath, shortFile)
command = ["convert", filePath, "+compress", newFile]
try:
    check_call(command)
except CalledProcessError as e:
    ...
```